# django websocker error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: django

I'm in the process of learning how to use websockets with django, I'm using django-websocket and here's a quick link to how they recommend setting it up https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#use-redispublisher-from-inside-django-views

I've setup redis and it's working okay, I've also got this view to send requests

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from ws4redis.publisher import RedisPublisher

class RenderView(View):
    facility = 'render-view'
    audience = {'broadcast': True}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RenderView, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
        self.redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility=self.facility, **self.audience)

    def get(self, request, message):
        self.redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
```

I call it using

```
...
message =  "Percentage {0}% \t {1}/{2} \t {3}".format(percentage, counter, (width * height), delta)
print message
socket = RenderView()
socket.get(request, message)
```

got stuck here with this error

```
    socket = RenderView()
  File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/revamp/gallery/socket.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(RenderView, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'
[19/Aug/2017 21:14:48] "POST /render-part HTTP/1.1" 500 18828
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your class `RenderView()`

the super class instantiation should be :

```
super(RenderView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```